# LINQ select all items of all subcollections that contain a string

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using jqueryui autocomplete to assist user in an item selection. I'm having trouble selecting the correct items from the objects' subcollections.
Object structure (simplified) is

```
public class TargetType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }

    public TargetType()
    {
        SubCategories = new HashSet<SubCategory>();
    }
}

public class SubCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SubTargetType> SubTargetTypes { get; set; }

    public SubCategory()
    {
        SubTargetTypes = new HashSet<SubTargetType>();
    }
}
```

Currently I'm doing this with nested foreach loops, but is there a better way?
Current code:

```
List<SubTargetResponse> result = new List<SubTargetResponse>();
foreach (SubCategory sc in myTargetType.SubCategories)
{
    foreach (SubTargetType stt in sc.SubTargetTypes)
    {
        if (stt.Name.ToLower().Contains(type.ToLower()))
        {
            result.Add(new SubTargetResponse {
                Id = stt.Id,
                CategoryId = sc.Id,
                Name = stt.Name });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `type` coming from?

Comment: It's just a string that contains the search parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do using `Linq` like this

```
var result = myTargetType.SubCategories
                         .SelectMany(sc => sc.SubTargetTypes)
                         .Where(stt => stt.Name.ToLower().Contains(type.ToLower()))
                         .Select(stt => new SubTargetResponse {
                                        Id = stt.Id,
                                        CategoryId = sc.Id,
                                        Name = stt.Name });
```

The above query doesn't work. The following should work, but I'd not recommend that as that'd not be faster or more readable.

```
var result = myTargetType.SubCategories
                         .Select(sc => new Tuple<int, IEnumerable<SubTargetType>>
                                            (sc.Id, 
                                             sc.SubTargetTypes.Where(stt => stt.Name.ToLower().Contains(type.ToLower()))))
                         .SelectMany(tpl => tpl.Item2.Select(stt => new SubTargetResponse {
                                        Id = stt.Id,
                                        CategoryId = tpl.Item1,
                                        Name = stt.Name }));
```

Comment: This doesn't compile. On row `CategoryId = sc.Id,` error "sc does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that! I've updated the answer, but as I've mentioned, I'd probably not recommend that.

Comment: So would it be better to stick with the nested loops?

Comment: I'd say, Yes. First, most of the time there's no performance gain with `Linq` if the non-Linq code (with for, if-else etc) is written properly. Because, Linq methods will do the same things internally. The huge benefit of `Linq` is the compact code and enhanced readability. Here, it doesn't provide either. Rather degrades the performance a bit (`new Tuple<,>()` part).

Comment: @Sami We could have done the same with multiple `ToList().ForEach()` as well. But again, that'd not do any better. Read this if you haven't already http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx

Comment: @Sami you could use anonymous types with `new {ID = ..., SubTTypes = ...}` syntax instead of a Tuple and the syntax of the second approach would become more concise and readable again.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are 2 different questions.

> LINQ select all items of all subcollections that contain a string

Solutions:

(A) LINQ syntax:

```
var result =
    (from sc in myTargetType.SubCategories
     from stt in sc.SubTargetTypes.Where(t => t.Name.ToLower().Contains(type.ToLower()))
     select new SubTargetResponse
     {
         Id = stt.Id,
         CategoryId = sc.Id,
         Name = stt.Name
     })
    .ToList();
```

(B) Method syntax:

```
var result =
    myTargetType.SubCategories.SelectMany(
        sc => sc.SubTargetTypes.Where(stt => stt.Name.ToLower().Contains(type.ToLower())),
        (sc, stt) => new SubTargetResponse
        {
             Id = stt.Id,
             CategoryId = sc.Id,
             Name = stt.Name
        })
    .ToList();
```

> Currently I'm doing this with nested foreach loops, but is there a better way?

Well, it depends of what do you mean by "better". Compare your code with LINQ solutions and answer the question. I personally do not see LINQ being better in this case (except no curly braces and different indentation, but a lot of a hidden garbage), and what to say about the second LINQ version in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33581914/linq-select-all-items-of-all-subcollections-that-contain-a-string/33581975#33581975) - if that's "better" than your code, I don't know where are we going.

Comment: By a "better way" I meant more readable and/or better performance. The first answer assured me that there isn't and I should stick with the loops.

Comment: @Sami I see. So you saw that LINQ in this case is neither more readable, nor performant. The later is almost always true :-) And for readability LINQ is usually better, but not here, and the second (working) variant in the accepted answer is just ridiculous. The correct port (version (A) of mine) is basically the same as with loops. So yeah, stay on loops :-)